# javascript - function forEach this.get

Tags: javascript

I made this in jquery and it works fine,
but I need to make it in pure javascript.
The following code doesn't works, I don't understand why...
I'm not expert in javascript...

```
function playVideo() {
    var popo = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    popo.forEach(function(index){ 
          var obj = this.get(0);
          obj.playVideo(); 
    });
}
```

Update: I will try to post my workin jquery version

```
function pauseVideo() {
    $("object").each(function(index){ 
          obj = $(this).get(0);
          obj.pauseVideo(); 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodeList, and even though it's array-like, it doesn't have array methods like forEach, some, every etc. so you have to iterate the old fashion way

```
function playVideo() {
    var popo = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
    for (var i=0; i<popo.length; i++) {
        popo[i].playVideo(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for my code... maybe I must post my jquery working jquery?

Comment: I was wondering what `get()` was doing, but I suspect you're trying to use jQuery methods on DOM nodes, and if you're using jQuery, why on earth would be doing it this way to begin with ?

Comment: Yeah, not sure I get it, what is `playVideo` and `pauseVideo` and how are those methods chainable to plain DOM nodes ?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `$(popo[i]).playVideo();` and that `playVideo` is a jQuery plugin ?

Comment: You're going to have to explain this a lot better. You have a function called playVideo, it's the one in the code above, but what are you expecting when you do `obj.playVideo()`, what function do you have with that name that can be chained onto a native DOM node. Where are you getting `element.playVideo()` from ?

Comment: i have two videos (two <object> elements), and i want to play all these two videos.. are youtube videos... my jquery example works fine... but I need the pure javascript way for run the code from my browser console

Comment: But with what? Do you have a `playVideo()` function other than the one in the posted code, or did you just make it up ?

Comment: And now they are youtube videos, so `playVideo()` is part of the Youtube API

Comment: is it possible to convert my jquery version into pure javascript??

Comment: Yes, it's in the answer above. Open your browser console (F12) and check for errors.

Comment: when I paste your code in the console and I press return, there is one error: undefined http://oi57.tinypic.com/z1hjc.jpg

Comment: have a look please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585080/chrome-run-javascript-function-from-browser-console-undefined

Answer (score 0):

Because selector functions like `getElementsByTagName` return `NodeList` objects, and not `Array` objects.

Two fixes:

- manually convert to array: `yesArray = [].slice.call(noArray)` so you can `yesArray.forEach(...`
- add `forEach` to `NodeList`: `NodeList.prototype.forEach = [].forEach`

I like the second, but it's not 'correct' according to some:

```
// Somewhere in your lib:
NodeList.prototype.forEach = [].forEach;

// In app code:
var popo = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
popo.forEach(function(index) {
  .. etc
});
```

Comment: Maybe it's nicer to do `Array.slice.call` instead of `[].slice.call`? I think it's a little clearer.

Comment: @jaapz - The proper way would be `Array.prototype.slice.call()`

Comment: `Array.slice` is a function? You might mean `Array.prototype.slice`, which is way too much to type.

Comment: @adeneo 'proper' =) I like that.

Comment: Yeah, typo, that's what i meant :) I think code clarity beats 'typing a lot'.

Comment: I think `[].slice` is very clear, but I type that sometimes, so I know it. That's why I like fix 2: add array methods to NodeList, the sensible way DOM should've worked.

Comment: guys in don't understand... still doesn't work: can you post the code please?

Comment: Voila. Updated answer.