# chrome - run javascript function from browser console "undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I want to run a javascript function from the browser console,
I'm trying to do it in Chrome (windows 7) and my function is this:

```
function playVideo() {
    var popo = document.getElementsByTagName("object");
      for (var i=0; i<popo.length; i++) {
        popo[i].playVideo(); 
      }
  }
```

normally this function works fine when I fire it from a webpage

```
<button onclick="playVideo();">play</button>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:playVideo();">play</a>
```

but if I paste it into the browser console, and I press Return,
it doesn't work and there is this error:
"undefined"
http://oi57.tinypic.com/z1hjc.jpg
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: you just defined a function. Call it.

Comment: I've tried to call it, but without success.. I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After paste to console and pressing return you must call this function by name, in you case, after "undefined" write to consle "playVideo()" and press Return.

Comment: after paste to console, press return, and after "undefined" write "playVideo()" and press enter, it says again: "undefined"...

Comment: ooook!!!! I was trying on Jsfiddle! On Jsfiddle it doesn't work, but after that I tried on my website and it works!! thank you!